# Dont terminate program in epoll_wait

Tags: c, linux, signals, epoll

I want to handle if `epoll_wait` was interrupted by any reason (for example by SIGINT)

```
while ( true ) {
    n = epoll_wait ( epoll_fd, events, max_events, -1 );
    if ( errno == EINTR ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But debugger did not even go to `if`. Program was terminated in `epoll_wait`. I've added some magick:

```
signal ( SIGINT, placebo );
while ( true ) {
    n = epoll_wait ( epoll_fd, events, max_events, -1 );
    if ( errno == EINTR ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And all works as expected. But this is ugly. What is the right way to let me handle any `epoll_wait`'s interrupt?

Comment: `epoll` doesn't magically gobble up signals. You still have to handle signals yourself. I recommend a signalfd, though.

Comment: The default action for most signals (including `SIGTERM`) is to terminate the process. So in the 1st case you just are observing expected behaviuor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either handle signals or block them. If you just want to ignore EINTR I suggest blocking via the sigprocmask() or signal(signum, SIG_IGN) for a single-threaded process, or via pthread_sigmask() for a multithreaded process. If you want to actually do something, use sigaction() to install a handler.

Do not use signal() to set an actual handler. Its behavior varies across UNIX platforms. Read the manpages for details.